# Query paranthese data from SpreadSheet

Tags: regex, join, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to query my data from Sheet1 to Sheet2.
Sheet1 contains the original data. Sheet2 first 2 columns are reserved to query data from Sheet1.

I want to query A AND B from Sheet1 to sheet2.

Sample Original Data

```
Hello (Hey) Hi 25
Sample(Data) is this 36

Query
Hello (Hey)
```

I should get the whole row to sheet2 but because of the parenthesis, I can't get the result.

I am using the below formula to query my data from Sheet1 to Sheet2.

```
=query(Original!A:F, "where A matches '" & join("|", A:A) & "' AND B matches '" & join("|", B:B) & "'",0)
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets' `QUERY` function uses a pseudo-SQL syntax. I recommend reading up on it here: [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343). This doc provides a very good overview of the syntax and some helpful examples.

In general, the "query" portion of your formula needs to follow the syntax `select [column(s)] where [some condition]`.

In your case, it sounds like you just want the entirety of columns A and B from the original sheet—correct me if I've misunderstood your request—so you don't even need the condition:

```
=QUERY(Original!A:F,"select A, B")
```

Answer (score 0):

try simple array reference like:

```
={Original!A:B}
```

[image]